# How do I launch .net windows forms application with no visible windows?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, system-tray

I have a .net windows forms application that needs to open directly to the notify icon (system tray) with no visible windows.  I realize that I can do this in the onshown event or something like it.  But if I do that I get a flash of the window.  How can I avoid that flash?  I have tried modifying my `Program.cs` file to look like this:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

MainForm frm = new MainForm();
frm.Visible = false;
Application.Run(frm);
```

However this doesn't work either because `Application.Run()` makes the form visible.  I am pretty sure there is an easy answer that I am missing.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an overload for `Application.Run()` that takes in no parameters, and thus doesn't immediately show a form on application launch. Of course, you'll have to manage what causes the application to terminate yourself since there's no initial or 'main' form for it to monitor. So for example it'd be your notification icon, which I'm sure you'll be able to handle.

Comment: That is what I need, though I was using a timer on that form that doesn't work now so I have some application restructuring to do.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need a main form at the time you start your application, [here is a link](http://bluehouse.wordpress.com/2006/01/24/how-to-create-a-notify-icon-in-c-without-a-form/) to an article that describes how to create *just* a NotifyIcon.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting WindowState on frm to Minimized along with ShowInTaskbar to false.
Also, I'm no expert, but I think you should handle the visibility logic in the MainForm constructor.

Comment: After the forms class constructor is called, the `Application.Run` will override any visibility to true.

Comment: WOW! Setting WindowState=Minimized and ShowInTaskbar=false in the designer properties works!  So simple and so effective!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet from the initialization method of a form I have that does exactly that. The app runs in the tray and the window shows when the user double clicks the notify icon. I have methods that handle resizing, etc. that ensure the form will only be closed through a menu option.

```
public MainForm()
{
  ...code
  Resize += MainForm_Resize;
  notifyIcon.DoubleClick += NotifyIconDoubleClick;
  WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
  Hide();
}
private void MainForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (FormWindowState.Minimized == WindowState)
     Hide();
}

private void NotifyIconDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Show();
   try
   {
      WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
      ...more code for other stuff
    }catch(yadda yadda)
      ...code
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit hackish, but you can create a borderless Form (`FormBorderStyle.None`) and set it's `TransparencyKey` to it's `BackColor`, disable `ShowInTaskbar`, then give that form to Application.Run(). Voilà. :)