# Why is ShowInTaskbar freezing the application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to hide my `Form` at startup of the operating system(windows 7).
To accomplish that, I tried the solution:-

```
if (Program.Args == "/startup")
{
    this.Hide();
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
}
```

I had the above code in my form1_Load Event, `Program.Args` is the command line argument supplied to my program.

What is wrong in the above code?

How can I accomplish hiding of my form through command line arguments?

As some people suggested to use
`this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized`
`this.ShowInTaskbar = false` 
I tried it but my application freezes, like this:-

[image]

If I comment out the line
`this.ShowInTaskBar = false`
it runs normally but shows the icon in task bar.

Normal Look of the application is :-

[image]

Comment: Your code seems correct, Just put a break-point at if block and check whether your argument is correct or not.

Comment: I guess it is the only form you have. Then it is a main form. This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764745/how-to-hide-the-mainform-and-still-run-the-program  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70272/single-form-hide-on-startup

Comment: @Arshad I double checked, my command line arguments are correct.

Comment: are you wanting no visibility at all like a silent mode, or if it briefly shows is that alright?

Comment: No, I want that only it's icon should be visible in the notification tray and the form should not be visible to the user unless he clicks on the icon in notification tray

Comment: See this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978597/how-do-i-launch-net-windows-forms-application-with-no-visible-windows) it appears that if you set forms WindowState to minimized and to not be shown in taskbar it will work.

Comment: @MarkHall I tried your solution, but it is not working, please see the edited question.

Comment: Try it in your forms constructor after InitializeComponent.

Comment: @MarkHall It's already in my forms constructor

Comment: Why are you setting `ShowInTaskbar` to false *when you're hiding the form*? It's not going to show in the taskbar (or alt+tab menu) when it's hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like changing the visibility. I get an error code on your code because of conversion of Args to string ... but this works just fine.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Visible = false;
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but `this.Visible = false` doesn't work

Comment: What are you using as a code editor and compiler? Visual Studio 2012 is what I used, and it worked just fine.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012 , and also In any case the code should work whether you use Visual Studio or a normal csc.exe

Comment: Are you getting any error messages or just simply nothing happening? I am also on a different operating system, so I am going to get different results more than likely.

Comment: Nothing is happening.

Comment: Have you tried minimizing the form as its WindowState property in command line? like this:

    this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;

Comment: Yes I tried it but the problem is that when I write `this.ShowInTaskbar = false` the application freezes, without it it works normally.

Comment: Gotcha. is there any events following like an indefinite loop that it is entering or something?

Comment: No, if I  comment out this line then it runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }
```

Then create a icon for the tray and show tray icon

Comment: It's freezing the application, check the edited question

Comment: @ps06756 Using the designer for Visual Studio, can you F11 through and see if it is freezing up in the designer by where the reference is placed for the load event. is it getting stuck there when it is loading your application deigner?

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of the form (in VS) set next properties :

- `ShowInTaskbar = false`
- `WindowState = Minimized`

Best do this in the design form of VS not in the load event. If you are application is still freezing then please remove all other code except the clicking event on the notification icon to show the window. I simulate it with a clean form (only a button on it) and did not have a freezing problem. Here is the code that you have to execute when the user click on the notification icon:

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```